# Android KeyLogger (Java/NDK Api)

Tags: android, kernel, keyevent, keylogger, key-events

Good day.

I want to make an keylogger for android.

Please do not mix KeyLogger with the idea of `onTextChanged` of `EditText` as I want to be able to read the typed keys **OUT OF THE APPLICATION**

We know couple of things.

> No controls over the other applications due to the security of `DVM`.
>
> Java API (Android Cross-Platform Language) do not provide any option to listen for key events outside the application.
>
> We have [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) which I could not make work and neither could get the event when key was typed,for example, inside the other application.

**Important Notice: The idea is for self-progressing and has nothing to do with the further development and deployment to anywhere**

My question is the next.

As far as we can reckon, Java Api for Android do not provide any way for logging the key events outside the application, so are there any ways to achieve the desired? I am thinking about the key event logger through NDK like so:

> NDK is for native development, meaning we can have access up to the heart of the Android (Kernel) this is my assumption and I can be wrong though.
>
> NDK is being written with the C/C++ which is a native language for Android, meaning we can go deeper into the OS.

The last important part to notice. I wish do to the key logging **WITHOUT** rooting my phone, so please do not suggest rooting either.

Anyway this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway this can be achieved?

No, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

You are welcome to create your own custom ROM that contains your keylogger, then try to convince people to install your custom ROM on their device. However, I strongly recommend that you talk to your attorney first.

Comment: Speaking about deployment, I am not going to deploy anywhere as it is for my own use, and has nothing to do with the Globe, but yet i was thinking about NDK as mentioned, I reckon it might be possible through NDK

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: That would represent a massive security flaw if true.

Comment: Hmm that could be one